# D3 prevent distortion when zooming

Tags: d3.js, zooming, timeline

I am trying to get a timeline working in D3. As it supports zooming and panning, the `rects` must scale and be transformed when zooming, but I would like some text on there which should only be transformed in the x axis upon panning- I wish it to stay the same size regardlesss of how zoomed in we are and get rid of the ugly distortion on the x axis.

See http://jsfiddle.net/kLs7D/4/ for what I mean.

Comment: Just remove the scale from the text elements -- http://jsfiddle.net/kLs7D/5/ Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: The trouble with that approach is that if you zoom out loads then the text is no longer aligned on the x axis where it should be. Does that make sense?

Comment: Then you probably don't want to use `transform` at all but redraw with the new x axis -- http://jsfiddle.net/kLs7D/7/

Comment: Great, I'll add that as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid distortion, the best approach is not to apply the `transform` to the elements, but to redraw them using the modified scale:

```
svg.selectAll("rect.timebar").attr('x', function (d) {
        return x(d.start);
    })
    .attr('width', function (d) {
        return x(d.end) - x(d.start);
    });
svg.selectAll(".thetext").attr('x', function (d) {
        return x(d.start);
    });
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kLs7D/7/).